Comparing the original outer measure with that generated by the restricted outer measure
Given a premeasure $\mu$ on a semiring $\mathcal S$ on a set $X$, it's easy to see that the induced outer measure coincides with that induced by $\mu$'s extension to the generated ring. Thus, outer measure is unchanged as we pass from semiring to the generated ring. This motivates the question: Is the same true while going from ring to $\sigma$-ring?
In general, this is not true, for there can be several distinct extensions of the same premeasure (unless we assume $\sigma$-finiteness). But we know a "canonical" measure, namely the restriction of the induced outer measure, and we must consider this only if there's any hope for the outer measure preservation as asked above.
More precisely, consider a premeasure $\nu$ on a ring $\mathcal R$ on $X$. Then we have a measure $\tilde\nu$ on $\sigma(\mathcal R)$ extending $\nu$ which is given by the restriction of the induced outer measure $\nu^*$. Question: Is $\tilde\nu^* = \nu^*$? ("$\le$" is clear.)

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\r{\mathcal R}$The answer is yes.
Indeed, as you said, it is clear that $\bar\nu^*\le\nu^*$.
Take now any $E\in\si(\r)$. We want to show that $\nu^*(E)\le\bar\nu^*(E)$. Take any real $c>\bar\nu^*(E)$ (if such $c$ exists) and any real $\ep>0$. Then there is a countable family $(E_i)_{i\ge1}$ in $\si(\r)$ such that $E\subseteq\bigcup_{i\ge1} E_i$ and $\sum_{i\ge1}\bar\nu(E_i)<c$. Next, for each $i$ there is a countable family $(A_{i,j})_{j\ge1}$ in $\r$ such that $E_i\subseteq\bigcup_{j\ge1} A_{i,j}$ and $\sum_{j\ge1} \nu(A_{i,j})<\ep2^{-i}+\nu^*(E_i)=\ep2^{-i}+\bar\nu(E_i)$. So, $E\subseteq\bigcup_{i\ge1} E_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i,j\ge1} A_{i,j}$ and
$$\sum_{i,j\ge1} \nu(A_{i,j})<\ep+\sum_{i\ge1}\bar\nu(E_i)<\ep+c.$$
So, for any real $c$ and any real $\ep>0$,
$$\bar\nu^*(E)<c\implies\nu^*(E)<\ep+c.$$
Thus, $\nu^*(E)\le\bar\nu^*(E)$. $\quad\Box$

It's interesting to note that the same reasoning sails through if we replace $\sigma(\mathcal R)$ by any set containing $\mathcal R$. All that's really needed is that $\nu^*$ extends $\nu$ and this is ensured by $\nu$ being a measure on $\mathcal R$.

@Atom : Thank you for your comment.
